# Binding ContentControl Content with Window Content

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a window without titlebar.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.PopupWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize"
        AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent">
    <Border Margin="10">
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect Color="Black"
                              Direction="270"
                              BlurRadius="10"
                              ShadowDepth="3" />
        </Border.Effect>
        <Grid Background="White">
            <DockPanel>
                <DockPanel Name="titleBar"
                           DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                           Height="32"
                           Background="LimeGreen">
                    <TextBlock Padding="8"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Text="My Special Window"
                               Foreground="White"
                               FontWeight="999"
                               FontSize="16" />
                </DockPanel>
                <ContentControl Name="content" />
            </DockPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

I have malty Usercontrols that load in PopupWindow .

In viewmodel, i show this windows with different Content.

```
SearchViewModel vm = new SearchViewModel();
SearchView view = new SearchView();
view.DataContext = vm;
PopupWindow window = new PopupWindow();
window.Owner = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsActive);
window.Content = view;
window.ShowDialog();
```

Searchview set for PopupWindow content, but i want to set searchview for Content of ContentControl. How do i this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting Content on Window, set it directly on your ContentControl:

```
window.content.Content = view;
```

Comment: Thanks, but i set content for windows in another class so i don't access to content control.

Comment: It is accessible from other class as well. Have you tried accessing it?

Comment: No, I use `<ContentControl Name="content" x:FieldModifier="public"/>`

Comment: Yeah you need `x:FieldModifier="public"` in case they are in separate assemblies. But in case class is in same assembly, you can access it directly.